# How do i delete a particular sheet in a flat file with python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, xlsx

Im trying to write a loop that browses through my directory to find a file that starts with a particular filename('TVC') and deletes a specific sheet within that file. In the below case 'Opt-Ins' is the name of one of the sheets I want to delete

My attempt-

```
import os
path = 'C:/Users/grr/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Matching'
files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and \
         'TVC' in i]
    
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(files)
if 'Opt-Ins' in wb.sheetnames:
    wb.remove(wb['Opt-Ins'])
wb.save(files)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I just want to delete a specific sheet. how do I do this?

Comment: `del` would delete the reference in the list, not remove it from your local directory. Which one are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, `in` doesn't check if it begins with `"TVC"` it just checks if it's within the name somewhere.

Comment: @monk thats wrong on my part. do you have a better solution? would something like this work from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(file_workbook)
if 'Sheet1' in wb.sheetnames:
    wb.remove(wb['Sheet1'])
wb.save(file_workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call `load_workbook` on a *list of filenames*:

```py
wb = load_workbook(files)
```

You need to loop over the files, and run your code on each file in the loop:

```py
for filename in files:
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    ...  # rest of your code here
```

It looks like you do understand loops, so I assume this was just an oversight. Don't forget to take breaks when programming. In my experience, the chance of making a mistake like this greatly increases when I work for too long without a break.

Comment: thank you for your response. should i keep files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and \
         'TVC' in i] as this or does files will just be my path

Comment: the problem is that if i use files i get an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~$TVC Membership List 04-01-22 for oo.xlsx'. this seems  like it an issue with how im defining files. is there a better way? perhaps something like files = 
    if f_name.startswith('TVC')  @shadowtalker

Comment: @JoeTha `files` is not a magic special variable. You must define it by looping over the contents of a directory, as you did in your question.

Comment: @JoeTha you must check for files that _start with_ `TVC`, or you must otherwise exclude those temporary files with names that start with `~$`. The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Learning to read and understand error messages is an essential skill in programming.

Comment: Thank you for your well intentioned response. I will definitely keep it in mind going further and also take breaks. If you found my question useful. please upvote it or suggest how i can ask better questions in the future as im a budding py dev. Thank you